# Yii2 OrderBy в HasOne

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Есть связь

```
 return $this->hasOne(Neighbourhood::className(), ['slug' => 'url'])->onCondition(['neighbourhood.city_id' => $this->city_id]);
```

Которая потом через joinWith подключается.
Как сделать сортировку в этой связи?

```
return $this->hasOne(Neighbourhood::className(), ['slug' => 'url'])->onCondition(['neighbourhood.city_id' => $this->city_id])->orderBy('neighbourhood.name');
```

не работает,
если указывать потом в подключаемом запросе, тоже не работает. Если убрать onCondition то сортировка начинает работать.

Comment: `orderBy('neighbourhood.name')` => `orderBy('neighbourhood.name DESC')` или `orderBy(['neighbourhood.name' => SORT_DESC])`

Comment: я же написал в примере, не работает так

Comment: Покажите как в запросе используете, тогда уж

Comment: LinkPage::find() ->joinWith('subways') ->joinWith('areas') ->joinWith('addresses') ->joinWith('landmark') ->orderBy('subway.name, neighbourhood.name') ->all();